# Are there commands in Gcc to get the description of a keywords(or functions etc)?

Tags: c++, c, gcc

Previosly i used turboc++, but recently shifted to codeblocks and sometimes i also use notepad (i compile code using gcc via command promt, though possible in codeblocks). Now previously, in turbo c++ i used ctrl+F1 to get help for particular function or keywords or headerfiles etc, by keeping the cursor line on the keywords, the help is regarding the description of what the function does, whatever etc. Now in gcc(or in code::blocks) i want to know is it possible to get the help for, lets say for a perticular keyword, using some commands in gcc under command prompt?
(not sure, but i heard it is possible in clang).

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's a plugin for that in C::B.

Comment: can u say the name please

Comment: I have no clue, since I don't use it, but I'm pretty sure I've seen one like that.

Comment: thanks for the reply, But hey if u dont mind can i ask you what compiler you use?

Comment: Ever considered using `emacs`?

Comment: GCC itself has no such facility.

Comment: Well just started googling it.Do you think i should use it , well in
the sense i am a starter of new ide's

Comment: `the help is regarding the description of what the function does, whatever etc` This is art.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is an IDE.

There are many, many choices.  I'd strong recommend looking at Eclipse CDT:

- http://www.eclipse.org/cdt/
- http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-eclipse-stlcdt/

PS:

The "C:B" referred to above is "Code Blocks".  That might also be a good choice for you - check it out, too:

- http://www.codeblocks.org/

Comment: hey thanks for reply. but iam sure iam not looking for ide(i forget to say, i sometimes use eclipse too). out of curiosity i want to know if such commands exist.

Comment: hey one more thing,thanks for sites,just checked out, they are a lot cool.

Comment: Of course, there's always command line `man 3 fopen` or `info fopen` on Linux ... but I don't think that's what you're looking for.  You *cannot* lookup APIs or do any kind of "auto-complete" from Gcc itself, if that's what you're asking.  You need an "IDE".  Which can be anything from a vim or emacs plugin to MS Visual Studio.  'Hope that helps!